# Can I display different layout components based on different conditions of state in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

Say for instance you have an application with a landing page and you want this landing page to either show a log in button if your user is not logged in, or display the users name in a text view if the user is indeed logged in.

Is it a must to create two slightly different layouts to inflate based on the condition of being logged in? Or is there a way to decide at runtime which layout component will be necessary given the state of the application?

If the latter is true, how do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is true.

Android provides a way to provide different layouts given certain [device configurations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) but doesn't go further than this.

In both cases, you'd still have to create multiple layout resources (whether you inflated them yourself at runtime, after checking your condition, or if you wanted the system to pick the correct layout).

Depending on the extent that your UI changes, it may be worth creating not just two layouts, but also two `Activity`s, one for each state, where (before `setContentView(...)` to avoid unnecessary loading) you check your condition, and open the other activity if needed. This way, your business logic for one state won't be mixed with the other.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just as simple as showing a `TextView` instead of a `Button` why not just use `setVisibilty()` on each of them depending on your situation. If you have a more complicated layout then I would suggest having two separate layouts and inflating the correct one. Or as @ataulm suggested use separate activities

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I think that might work in this particular case.

Comment: +1 if it's really simple and the layout change isn't drastic, I'd go with this option.