# Image to a header of a navigation drawer and Login

Tags: java, android

I am having difficulty implementing two things in DRAWERMENU. In the header, I want to put the user's photo and name, which are in Firebase. In the menu, I want to make an option that for the ADMIN appear some items and for the user appear others.

Can you help me with some suggestions?

The following is the XML and the Java code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.DrawerBaseActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/content_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_menu"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```java
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private DrawerBaseActivity drawerBaseActivity;
private TextView nome_perfil;
private ImageView imagem_perfil;
private TextView user_email;
private Usuario usuario;

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer_base, null);
    FrameLayout container = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.activityContainer);
    container.addView(view);
    super.setContentView(drawerLayout);

    Toolbar toolbar = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    NavigationView navigationView = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 
    R.string.menu_drawer_open, R.string.menu_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_add:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, 
           AddPecaActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_addhist:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, 
             ddHistActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_addalbum:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddGaleriaActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_addnoticias:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddNoticiasActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;

        case R.id.menu_breve:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BrevementeActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_historico:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HistoricoActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.recyclerAlbuns:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MeusAlbunsActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_contacto:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactoActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_perfil:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PerfilActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_sair:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(drawerBaseActivity);
            builder.setTitle("Sair");
            builder.setMessage("Tem a certeza que pretende sair?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

protected void allocateActivityTitle(String titleString) {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
I'm new to java.
This is in Android Studio.
The first part is the XML
The second is the activity.

I didn't post the whole code, but basically in this DrawerBaseActivity I want the name and photo to appear in the HEADER.

The remaining doubt I will post later.

Comment: This is getting much better to be a question. The way it was initially, there was no context. I don't do android. So you have a UI and you want some components to appear when they're admin and some components to appear when they're a user?

Comment: yes that's exactly right

Comment: Did you  check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510330/can-i-display-different-layout-components-based-on-different-conditions-of-state